# Why does this bug happen when I click on two sprites at the same time?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a simple game using pygame where you keep clicking on tiles as fast as you can until you miss a tile. this is the progress I've made so far. sometimes when I click on a tile (usually when 2 tiles are next to each other and you click between them) one of them does what they're supposed to while the other just disappears from the screen.

```py
import pygame
import random
import sys

#Setting up all possible Tile positions
grid = [[0,0],  [0,150],  [0,300],  [0,450],  [0,600],
        [150,0],[150,150],[150,300],[150,450],[150,600],
        [300,0],[300,150],[300,300],[300,450],[300,600],
        [450,0],[450,150],[450,300],[450,450],[450,600],
        [600,0],[600,150],[600,300],[600,450],[600,600]]
taken = []

#Classes
class Cursor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pic):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load(pic).convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (50,50))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def destroyTile(self):
        pygame.sprite.spritecollide(cursor, tileGroup, True)
    
    def update(self):
        self.rect.topleft = pygame.mouse.get_pos()  

class Tiles(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, tileSize, color, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface(([tileSize, tileSize]))
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = [x, y]

def drawTiles():
    takenLen = len(taken)
    while takenLen != 3:
        m = random.randint(0,24)
        x, y = grid[m]
        if grid[m] not in taken:
            blackTile = Tiles(150, black, x, y)
            blackTile.add(tileGroup)   
            taken.append(grid[m])
            takenLen += 1
        
def handleTiles():
    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    modx = mx % 150
    mody = my % 150
    x = mx - modx
    y = my - mody
    taken.remove([x, y])
    drawTiles()   

def drawRedTile():
    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    modx = mx % 150
    mody = my % 150
    x = mx - modx
    y = my - mody
    redTile = Tiles(150, red, x, y)
    redTile.add(tileGroup)

#Colours
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
grey = (46, 46, 46)

#Initializing Pygame
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Screen
screenWidth = 750
screenHeight = 900
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth, screenHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption("Tiles Game")
whiteSurface = pygame.Surface((750, 750))
whiteSurface.fill(white)
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

#Blue line
line = pygame.Surface((750, 10))
line.fill(blue)

#Groups
tileGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
cursor = Cursor("cursor.png")
cursorGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
cursorGroup.add(cursor)

score = 0

drawTiles()
while True:

    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            score += 1
            print(score)
            print(taken)
            print(tileGroup) 
            cursor.destroyTile()
            handleTiles()
        

    #Background
    screen.fill(grey)
    screen.blit(whiteSurface, (0,0))
    screen.blit(line, (0,750))
    
    tileGroup.draw(screen)
    cursorGroup.draw(screen)
    cursorGroup.update()

    pygame.display.update()
```

In the code I tried using print statements to see if the tile that seems to have disappeared is still there. When this happens, I assume that the tile is not in its group anymore since the number of sprites in the tile group went from 3 to 2. But the list showing all the taken positions still shows that there are 3 positions that are taken. I can still click on the tile if I just click on the space where there should be a tile and the tile comes back. I thought the game should exit when a tile isn't clicked on but it doesn't if there is an "invisible" tile in that position.

How do I make it so that this bug doesn't happen and every new tile made is visible?

Comment: Can you please [edit] to pose a clear, precise question? Maybe your question can be inferred, but it's good practice and etiquette to actually ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the cursor has an area and can hit more than one block at a time. So in `destroyTile` more than 1 block can be removed at once:

> ```py
> def destroyTile(self):
>    pygame.sprite.spritecollide(cursor, tileGroup, True)
> ```

However, the function `handleTiles` cannot handle this, because it can only remove one block position from the `taken` list. I suggest to simplify the code and recreate the `taken` list completely from `tileGroup` when blocks are removed:

```py
def handleTiles():
    taken.clear()
    for tile in tileGroup:
        x, y = tile.rect.topleft
        taken.append([x, y])
    drawTiles()
```